# XML response from asp page

Tags: php, xml, ajax, curl, asp-classic

I have been trying to send xml message from php to asp and output response to my php page using CURL but having no luck in receiving any response. This is what I have tried:

```
<?php
$url = "https://someweb.asp";
$post_string = "xmlmessage=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<abc>
<UserId>123</UserId> 
</abc>";

//$header  = "POST HTTPS/1.0 \r\n";
$header = "Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
$header .= "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)." \r\n";
$header .= "Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n"; 
$header .= $post_string;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

if ($output == false || $info['http_code'] != 200) {
  $output = "No cURL data returned for $url [". $info['http_code']. "]";
  if (curl_error($ch))
    $output .= "\n". curl_error($ch);
  }
else
    {curl_close($ch);}

echo $output;
?>
```

Can anyone please guide me where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't build a custom request for a simple POST. CURL is perfectly capable of doing a post without all those shenanigans:

```
$xml = <<<EOL
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<abc>
<UserId>123</UserId> 
</abc>
EOL;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('xmlmessage' => $xml));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die(curl_error($ch));
}

echo $result
```

Comment: I get this when I tried your code:Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: Invalid curl configuration option in /home/add.php on line 25
Bad Request (Invalid Number)

Comment: line 25 : curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST_FIELDS, array('xmlmessage' => $xml));

Comment: sorry, typo on my part. should be CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS (only one `_`)

Comment: awesome. what about javascript?
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","https://someweb.asp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<abc>
<UserId>123</UserId> 
</abc>");
}

Comment: If that .asp page is on a server OTHER than the one you're loading this page/script from, you can't do it. Look up 'same origin' security policy for JS/ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
$post_string = "xmlmessage=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<abc>
<UserId>123</UserId> 
</abc>";
```

swap the double and single quotes

```
$post_string = 'xmlmessage=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<abc>
<UserId>123</UserId> 
</abc>';
```

single quotes are not valid in xml markup

Comment: that didn't help. I get the error: "~No xmlmessage= parameter was provided" when I do this:<form method='POST' action='https://someweb.asp'>
  <input type='hidden' name='UserId' value='123'  >
  <input type='submit' value='go'>
  </form>