# XML response on PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML response from asp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759056/xml-response-from-asp-page)

I have been trying to send xml message from php to asp and output response to my php page using CURL but having no luck in receiving any response. This is what I have tried:

```
<?php

$post_string = "xmlmessage=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
$url = "https://someweb.asp"; 
<abc>
<UserId>123</UserId> 
</abc>";

//$header  = "POST HTTPS/1.0 \r\n";
$header = "Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
$header .= "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)." \r\n";
$header .= "Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n"; 
$header .= $post_string;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

if ($output == false || $info['http_code'] != 200) {
  $output = "No cURL data returned for $url [". $info['http_code']. "]";
  if (curl_error($ch))
    $output .= "\n". curl_error($ch);
  }
else
    {curl_close($ch);}

echo $output;
?>
```

Can anyone please guide me where i am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<?php
//do not put the $url within the XML (like in your original post)
$url = "https://someweb.asp"; 

$post_string =<<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<abc>
<UserId>123</UserId> 
</abc>
XML;

$post_string='xmlmessage='.rawurlencode($post_string);
echo $post_string;

/*
//$header  = "POST HTTPS/1.0 \r\n";
$header = "Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
$header .= "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)." \r\n";
$header .= "Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n"; 
$header .= $post_string;
*/

$ch = curl_init($url);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);

//get rid of the following and use the POST headers    
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);

//add the following two headers (for POST requests)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_string);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

if ($output == false || $info['http_code'] != 200) {
  $output = "No cURL data returned for $url [". $info['http_code']. "]";
  if (curl_error($ch))
    $output .= "\n". curl_error($ch);
  }
else
    {curl_close($ch);}

echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: I get SSL conection timeout now. thanks for the help

Comment: I just tested the code provided above on an SSL connection and it works fine.  Perhaps, the following might be of some help: http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/php-curl-ssl-connection-timeout/

Comment: did you add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); to your code? I see that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772146/xml-response-error you are NOT using that option.