# xml response error

Tags: php, html, xml, curl

I get SSL connection timeout error when I try sending xml message and expect a response:

```
$xml = <<<EOL
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<abc>
<UserId>123</UserId> 
</abc>
EOL;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('xmlmessage' => $xml));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die(curl_error($ch));
}

echo $result
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You find the [FAQ here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the search-field is located above in the top-right corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the code above you are missing:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Other than that, you need to make sure curl has ssl support.  Create a file named "test.php" and put the following in it:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

then load the page via your browser.  On the output, scroll down towards the "middle" of the page where 
you can see details about the modules installed/enabled.  Look for the curl information. If it has SSL support
you will see something SIMILAR to (notice how it "mentions" ssl):

```
cURL Information    libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.15 libssh2/1.2.6
```

Otherwise you'll need to contact the server admin to have him/her install ssl support for it.